# Is it possible to build debug and release versions at the same time?

Tags: android

Every time when I need to build the debug and release ver for the QA what I do:

1. In BuildVariants change to Debug make a build APK.
2. Then I change the BuildVariants to Release and build one more APK.

So, question is if it is possible to build two versions at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the root folder of the proyect, you can compile the debug version using the command line:

```
gradlew.bat assembleDebug
```

Or if you want to compile a release:

```
gradlew.bat assembleRelease
```

Takng that into account, you can create a script, named "compile.bat" for example, with this content:

```
@echo off
title Compiling...
echo Compiling the debug and realease apk's...

gradlew.bat assembleDebug
gradlew.bat assembleRelease

@echo Finished!
pause
```

Comment: this will build the Debug and Release version _sequentially_

Comment: Why it's necessary to build them at the same time?

Comment: Could you please explain more about the script? Where I need to put the script and how to execute it? Thanks

Comment: You only need to create a .bat file with that content inside the root of the proyect and run it.
You can run the script by simply double clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an APK through the terminal, then you can launch as many build processes as you like.

`$ ./gradlew assembleFlavouraFlavourbRelease & ./gradlew assembleFlavouraFlavourbDebug &`